# Jquery/Javascript calendar implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar

I need to implement a JS calendar into my webpage where I need to display JSON data wrt calendar dates. I need to be able to configure the look and appearance of the calendar so a regular off-the-shelf calendar plugin like fullCalendar.js is proving to be too complex to implement.

I just need to figure out a week-view and a day-view for the data implementation. Is there a starting point I should be looking at? I have the JSON ready. I just need the calendar implementation. Since there are many things such as leap year to take care of, I thought it'd be better to ask the experts before starting out on hte wrong path.

**WHAT I NEED**
For a day-view of the calendar, I only need the top header of the calendar, notably, the names of the days of the week in the Header (Sun/Mon/Tue..) from which if a user selects a day, the respective JSON data for that day is displayed below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [jQuery.datepicker()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) ?

All the options you're requesting should be configurable or easily extendable.

Comment: more than trying a plugin, i want to write it myself. i just need some guides keep things in mind.. just a small snippet of code to start things..

Comment: Ok. So you just would use .getJSON() then parse the data right?  Which part are you having trouble with getting started?